# What is a service mesh?

Tags: cloud, microservices, distributed-computing, terminology, servicemesh

In the context of cloud computing, backend developers frequently refer to building (or using) "service mesh" but I don't fully understand what it is. Can you tell more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a distributed application, each part of the application is called a microservice and is assigned a very basic task to do. This can be "return profile information" or even smaller one.

All these microservices need to talk between each other to make up the entire application. That is exactly what a service mesh provide. In fact, a service mesh describes both:

- all the network of microservices that an application use;
- as well as the software that make it possible to let them interact together.

A very popular service mesh software is Istio, which you generally find in large applications that have transitionned from monolith architecture. But keep in mind that there are [downsides to use a service mesh](https://www.bearer.sh/blog/what-is-a-service-mesh) and more generally to adopt a [distributed application](https://segment.com/blog/goodbye-microservices/).

Answer (score 3):

In a typical distributed application architecture based on microservices, few of the functionalities that were present in centralized manner were moved into microservices level such that the business logic module handles functionalities & related business logic and the network functions take care of inter service communication, redundancy, health monitor, service discovery etc. The orchestration combined with containers and microservices helped in bringing in management of cloud setups and the scalability, however there was also a need for extensively managing the end-to-end (service to service) connectivity between the services & communication between them and also to reduce complexity at individual microservices in maintaining the inter service communications, resiliency, health monitor, service discovery etc..  This brought in the need for service mesh. Service mesh typically comes above CNI and and builds on its capabilities.

With the help of service mesh, the logic governing service-to-service communication has been pulled out of individual microservices and abstracted in the form of an infrastructure layer. All the inter service communication activities have been offloaded to service mesh which in-turn provides built-in support for network functions like redundancy, service discovery, health monitor etc. Hence, with a service mesh, all the service-to-service communications shall happen on-top of a software component called service mesh (or side-car proxy) and the microservices do not directly communicate with the other microservices.

Answer (score 1):

*The term service mesh is used to describe the network of microservices that make up such applications and the interactions between them [[src]](https://istio.io/v1.9/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#what-is-a-service-mesh).*
Service mesh enables managed, observable, and secure communication across your services, letting you create robust enterprise applications made up of many microservices on your chosen infrastructure.

*A service mesh architecture uses a proxy instance called a sidecar in whichever development paradigm is in use, commonly containers and/or microservices. In a microservice application, a sidecar will attach to each service. In a container, the sidecar is attached to each application container, VM or container orchestration unit, such as a Kubernetes pod [[src]](https://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/definition/service-mesh).*

**Sidecar Proxy** : A sidecar proxy runs alongside a single instance or pod. Sidecars can handle tasks abstracted from the service itself, such as route, or proxy, traffic to and from the container it runs alongside, monitoring and security. Sidecars and their interactions make up what is called the data plane in a service mesh.

**Control Plane** : *The control plane manages tasks such as creating instances, monitoring and implementing policies for network management and security. Control planes can connect to a CLI or a GUI interface for application management [[src]](https://searchitoperations.techtarget.com/definition/service-mesh).*

[image]
[img src](https://www.nginx.com/blog/what-is-a-service-mesh/)